# How to draw Polyline without rendering map using coordinates

Tags: react-native, svg, maps, mapbox, polyline

I have array of coordinates and I can draw polyline on map using theese coordinates without problem.

Now what I want to do is, only drawing a polyline to screen without rendering the map.

Below is first few items of my coordinates array:

```
[
            [6.56674, 45.39881],
            [6.56682, 45.399],
            [6.56701, 45.39959],
            [6.56727, 45.40006],
            [6.56738, 45.4003],
            [6.56745, 45.40041],
            [6.56757, 45.40053]
]
```

[image: Drawen polyline on the map]

I want to draw the same polyline to black background without rendering map.

I tried to draw svg polyline using the array of coordinates but I couldn't achieved what I wanted only a dot appeared on the screen. Didn't draw a polyline.

```
import {Svg, Polyline} from 'react-native-svg';

<Svg height="100" width="100">
        <Polyline
          points={MY_ARRAY_OF_COORDS.map(item => `${item[0]},${item[1]`).join(" ")}
          fill="none"
          stroke="blue"
          strokeWidth="5"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
</Svg>
```

Comment: For svg can work on the you display's x and y coordinates then map coordinates. so technically it is not possible using svg.

Comment: @ronakdholariya so how can I achieve it? Are there other ways of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<polyline>` is actually rendered but almost invisible since the **coordinates are very close to each other**.

So you need to calculate a **scale factor**.

#### Js example

```js
const coords= [
            [6.56674, 45.39881],
            [6.56682, 45.399],
            [6.56701, 45.39959],
            [6.56727, 45.40006],
            [6.56738, 45.4003],
            [6.56745, 45.40041],
            [6.56757, 45.40053]
];

//calculate coordinate range for a scale factor
let xArr = coords.map((val)=>{return val[0]} );
let xMin = Math.min(...xArr);
let xMax = Math.max(...xArr);
let yArr = coords.map((val)=>{return val[1]} );
let yMin = Math.min(...yArr);
let yMax = Math.max(...yArr);

let xRange = xMax- xMin;
let yRange = yMax- yMin;
let scale = 100/Math.max(...[xRange, yRange]);
//console.log(xRange, yRange, scale)


//scale coordinates
coords.forEach(function(coord){
  let [x,y] =[coord[0], coord[1]];
  coord[0] = (x-xMin)*scale;
  coord[1] = (y-yMin)*scale;
})

//draw polyline
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const polyline = svg.querySelector('polyline');
polyline.setAttribute('points', coords.join());
```

```css
svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:visible
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
        <polyline
          points=""
          fill="none"
          stroke="blue"
          strokeWidth="10"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
</svg>
```

First we need to calculate ranges for x and y values (so the maximum distances between maximum and minimum x).

```
let xRange = xMax- xMin; //0.000829999999999664
let yRange = yMax- yMin; //0.001720000000005939
```

If you need a svg bounding box of 100x100 units the scaling factor would be:

```
let scale = 100/Math.max(...[xRange, yRange]);
```

Eventually we need to subtract the minimum x and y offsets to align the polyline to the x/y axes origin.

Comment: alternatively you could just set a viewBox and have all this scaling done for you.

Comment: @RobertLongson ... but you would have to compute an appropriate `stroke-width`...

Comment: @Robert Longson: that's true but AFAIK it's trickier to do this in react-native since there is no `getBBox()` method. But maybe this has been implemented in the meantime.  However, scaling coordinates would also avoid the need for very high floating point accuracy.